# Problem in rule about root multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been reading other similar problems like [this](http://twitter.com/ssiiaabb?lang=es), however I can not understand.

Basically the answer they give in that problem is that ALWAYS this rule must be followed.
$\forall a,b \ge 0, \ \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$

Take, $b = -3$ and $a > 0$

According to Wolframalpha, [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B-3%7D%5Csqrt%7Ba%7D%3D%5Csqrt%7B-3a%7D) is true:

$\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{-3a}$

So, my question is:

Must be: $a$ **and** $b \geq 0$  or must be: $a$ **or** $b \geq 0$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What does $\sqrt{-3}$ *mean*? If it stands for **a** square root of $-3$, then, yes, if $a\geqslant 0$ and if $\sqrt a$ is **the** non-negative root of $a$, $\sqrt{-3}\sqrt a$ is indeed **a** square root of $-3a$ and, in this sense, it is equal to $\sqrt{-3a}$.

If $\sqrt{-3}$ is a specific square root of $-3$, it's up to you to tell us *which* square root of $-3$ you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\forall a, b \ge 0$ means "for all $a$ *and* $b$ that are *both* greater than 0". In any similar expression, all of the listed variables must have the given property. To write "for all $a$ and $b$ where at least one of them is greater than 0", you would need to write that out explicitly or use an equivalent expression, e.g. $\forall a, b \mbox{ not both } < 0$.

Comment: My question is what of both are correct.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's answer is *technically* correct, but only under a different understanding of $\sqrt{}$ to how you normally treat it. The statement $\forall a, b \ge 0$ *always* refers to both $a \ge 0$ *and* $b \ge 0$. The fact that the statement might be true in other circumstances is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

For real numbers: in order for $\sqrt {a} \sqrt {b} = \sqrt {ab}$, $a$ and $b$ *must* be greater than or equal to zero, as square roots of negative numbers do not exist in the reals.

E.g. $$\sqrt {3} \sqrt {6} = \sqrt {18}$$ as $$\sqrt {3} \sqrt{3} \sqrt {2} = 3 \sqrt {2} \Leftrightarrow \sqrt {18} = \sqrt {9 \cdot 2} = 3 \sqrt {2}$$

Comment: Please review your answer as it has several errors involving forgetting the square root sign. For example, $\sqrt {-3} \sqrt {-2} \neq 3i \cdot 2i$ and $\sqrt {-3}\sqrt{2} \neq 3i \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I've removed the complex numbers section.

Answer (score 0):

We shall suspend the functional interpretation of $\sqrt{}$ in what follows until otherwise mentioned, and simply use it as shorthand for *square root.*

Let us examine $\sqrt2\sqrt{-3}.$

If we let $x=\sqrt 2$ and $y=\sqrt {-3},$ then it follows that $x^2=2$ and $y^2=-3,$ so that $$(xy)^2=2(-3)=-6,$$ or $$\sqrt2\sqrt-3=\sqrt{2(-3)}=\sqrt{-6}.$$

This is the sense in which WA means the above equation. However, care must be taken when both 'squares' are negative (even Euler mixed this up!).

Let us come back to the usual use of the symbol $\sqrt{}$ to denote the nonnegative square root of a number. Since by definition, nomnegativity (in general, order) applies only to real numbers, it follows that the function must be real-valued; also, since only nonnegative real numbers have square roots (basically because $(-)(-)=+$), the domain of this function is the nonnegative real numbers. This is the sense in which you first explained. That is, in this sense of understanding the $\sqrt{}$ symbol, it doesn't make any sense to write $\sqrt{-3},$ for example, since $-3$ is simply not in the domain of this function.

Thus, the symbol may be used in various ways depending on context. However, contemporary mathematicians rarely write things like $\sqrt{-3}$ at all in any sense and stick to using the symbol $\sqrt{}$ functionally. Whenever they deal with what a 17th century mathematician might have written as $\sqrt{-3},$ for example, they simply use a less confusing notation like $3i,$ or whatever notation for complex numbers they like best or is most suitable for the problem at hand, sequences or matrices or whatnot.

Hope this helped clear some things.